# Master's Scholarship with CGPA less than 3 out of 4

Tags: masters, research-undergraduate

I am curious about can anyone land full free scholarship (data science, AI, ML) in any reputed university in USA, Canada, Japan, UK or any other country with CGPA less than 3 from a lower-tier university of a developing country?

In this scenario, the student has 3-4 journal publication(based on AI/ML/DL; impact factor 2+) wherein 2 of them the student is marked as the first author.

Thanks.

Comment: Many graduate _schools_ have a minimum requirement of a B-average GPA for admission to the graduate program, and will rarely care very much about the publication record, even if it is stellarafter; the publication record might interest the _Department_ into _admitting_ you but it will have to fight for you to get the _school_ to waive its requirement for a B-average GPA. If the applications are submitted through the graduate school instead of directly to the Department, the School might not even forward your application to the Department but just reject it out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

In the US acceptance might be possible as the decisions are made on more than just GPA, and publications would certainly be a positive.

A full scholarship is a bit more tentative, however, as they aren't especially common and the competition for those that exist is fierce.

For a doctoral program, however, landing a TA position (or RA) would be more likely. This would provide funding (for the teaching/research duties) as well as forgiveness of fees. But for a masters, that path would also be unlikely.

However, in the US, the normal path is from a bachelors directly into a doctoral program. And again, there is competition for limited slots, but the decisions are made on the basis of several factors, not GPA.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.